# Pandas - identifying dataframe values that start with value in a list

Tags: python, pandas

Say I have the following dataframe:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> d=pd.DataFrame()
>>> d['A']=['12345','12354','76','4']
>>> d['B']=['4442','2345','33','5']
>>> d['C']=['5553','4343','33','5']
>>> d
       A     B     C
0  12345  4442  5553
1  12354  2345  4343
2     76    33    33
3      4     5     5
```

And say I have 3 values of interest:

```
>>> vals=['123','76']
```

I am interested in determining which values in my dataframe start with any of the values in my list. There are 3 cases in my example: (0,A) starts with 123; (1,A) starts with 123; and (2,A) starts with 76.

Is there a way I can do this without looping through each of my values?

If I were interested in matching values exactly I could just do:

```
>>> d.isin(vals)
       A      B      C
0  False  False  False
1  False  False  False
2   True  False  False
3  False  False  False
>>>
```

And if I was interested in whether the values start with 1 particular value I could do:

```
>>> d.applymap(lambda x:x.startswith('123'))
       A      B      C
0   True  False  False
1   True  False  False
2  False  False  False
3  False  False  False
>>>
```

But how can I combine these two to find any value that starts with any value in my list?

Comment: you can do `df.apply(lambda x: x.str.contains('|'.join(vals)))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can construct a regex pattern and test each column in turn using `apply` with a lambda calling `str.contains`:

```
In [9]:
vals=['123','76']
v = ['^' + x for x in vals]
d.apply(lambda x: x.str.contains('|'.join(v)))

Out[9]:
       A      B      C
0   True  False  False
1   True  False  False
2   True  False  False
3  False  False  False
```

The resulting regex pattern:

```
In [10]:
'|'.join(v)

Out[10]:
'^123|^76'
```

**update**

Actually you can do this using `stack` and `unstack` so that you initially stack all columns into a single column, call `str.contains` with the regex pattern and then `unstack`ing back to the original form:

```
In [9]:
vals=['123','76']
v = ['^' + x for x in vals]
d.stack().str.contains('|'.join(v)).unstack()

Out[9]:
       A      B      C
0   True  False  False
1   True  False  False
2   True  False  False
3  False  False  False
```

This is a cleaner way of doing it compared to using `apply`

Answer (score 3):

You could do this:

```
d.applymap(lambda x: any([x.startswith(v) for v in vals]))
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternative solution, which doesn't use `.apply()`:

```
In [66]: search_re = '^(?:{})'.format('|'.join(vals))

In [67]: search_re
Out[67]: '^(?:123|76)'

In [69]: df.astype(str).stack().str.match(search_re).unstack()
Out[69]:
       A      B      C
0   True  False  False
1   True  False  False
2   True  False  False
3  False  False  False
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit complicated, but it seems the fastest solution.

You can use [`str.startswith`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.startswith.html) which works only with Series, so use `list` comprehension and [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) output. But need check more items in list `vals`, so use another list comprehension with [`numpy.logical_or`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.logical_or.html) with `reduce` which works with `numpy array` -  convert output of `concat` and last create `Dataframe` with same column and index as original and data are output of `numpy.logical_or`:

```
print ([pd.concat([d[col].str.startswith(i) for col in d], axis=1).values for i in vals])
[array([[ True, False, False],
       [ True, False, False],
       [False, False, False],
       [False, False, False]], dtype=bool), array([[False, False, False],
       [False, False, False],
       [ True, False, False],
       [False, False, False]], dtype=bool)]

print (np.logical_or.reduce(
      [pd.concat([d[col].str.startswith(i) for col in d], axis=1).values for i in vals]))
[[ True False False]
 [ True False False]
 [ True False False]
 [False False False]]

print(pd.DataFrame(np.logical_or.reduce(
      [pd.concat([d[col].strstartswith(i) for col in d], 
                 axis=1).values for i in vals]), 
                   index=d.index, columns=d.columns))

       A      B      C
0   True  False  False
1   True  False  False
2   True  False  False
3  False  False  False
```

**Timings**:

```
#[40000 rows x 3 columns]
d = pd.concat([d]*10000).reset_index(drop=True)


In [77]: %timeit (d.applymap(lambda x: any([x.startswith(v) for v in vals])))
1 loop, best of 3: 228 ms per loop

In [78]: %timeit (d.apply(lambda x: x.str.contains('|'.join(['^' + x for x in vals]))))
10 loops, best of 3: 147 ms per loop

In [79]: %timeit (d.astype(str).stack().str.match('^(?:{})'.format('|'.join(vals))).unstack())
10 loops, best of 3: 172 ms per loop

In [80]: %timeit (pd.DataFrame(np.logical_or.reduce([pd.concat([d[col].str.startswith(i) for col in d], axis=1).values for i in vals]), index=d.index, columns=d.columns))
10 loops, best of 3: 116 ms per loop
```